# How config for mod_fcgid Apache modules

Tags: apache-2.2

I get this error in server's error_log 
HTTP request length 132355 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)
when upload a files.

I want config  MaxRequestLen's size is bigger
I changed in  .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidMaxRequestLen 15728640
</IfModule>
```

but get this error:

```
[alert] .....xxxx/xxx/.htaccess FcgidMaxRequestLen not allowed here
```

then where can i config it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mod_fcgid documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) says that `FcgidMaxRequestLen` directive is allowed in server config and virtual host context.